# Extracting min and max salary from string

Tags: python, regex

What I want is to extract min/max range of salary from a text which contains either hourly or annual salary.

```
import re

# either of the following inputs should work
input1 = "$80,000 - $90,000 per annum"
input2 = "$20 - $24.99 per hour"

salary_text = re.findall("[\$0-9,\. ]*-[\$0-9,\. ]*", input1)

if salary_text and salary_text[0]:
    range_list = re.split("-", salary_text[0])

    if range_list and len(range_list) == 2:
        low = range_list[0].strip(' $').replace(',', '')
        high = range_list[1].strip(' $').replace(',', '')
```

Comment: you could create list with inputs `all_examples = [input1, input2]` and run `for input in all_examples:` - this way you can test code with all inputs without changing code.  Eventually you could create list with input and expected outputs `all_examples = [(input1, "80000", "90000"), (input2, "20", "24.99")]` and automatically check if results are correct `for input, expected_low, expected_hight in all_examples: ... low == expected_low ... high == expected_hight ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `,` commas are a nice twist.
I feel you are stripping them a bit late,
as they don't really contribute to the desired solution.
Better to lose them from the get go.

Calling `.findall` seems to be overkill for your problem specification --
likely `.search` would suffice.

> ```
> salary_text = re.findall("[\$0-9,\. ]*-[\$0-9,\. ]*", input1)
> ```

The dollar signs, similarly, do not contribute to the solution,
your regex could probably just ignore them if your inputs are fairly sane.
Or even scan for lines starting with `$` dollar, and *then* the regex ignores them.

> ```
> range_list = re.split("-", salary_text[0])
> ```

There is no need for this `.split` -- the regex could have done this for you already.
Here is what I recommend:

```
def find_range(text):
    if text.startswith('$'):
        m = re.search(r'([\d\.]+) *- *\$?([\d\.]+)', text.replace(",", ""))
        if m:
            lo, hi = m.groups()
            return float(lo), float(hi)
    return None, None


print(find_range('$80,000 - $90,000 per annum'))
print(find_range('$20 - $24.99 per hour'))
```

The raw string regex `r'[\d\.]+'` picks out one or more numeric characters,
which can include decimal point.
And putting `(` `)` parens around a regex makes it a capturing group --
we have two such groups here.
Finally,  `*- *\$?` lets us skip a single `-` dash with optional whitespace
and at most one optional `$` dollar sign.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is an excellent solution.

Comment: What's your reasoning behind doing `if text.startswith('$'): …` as a separate test?

Comment: Could probably simplify the regex too `([\d\.]+).+?([\d\.]+)` since you don't really care what's in between the two numbers

Answer (score 1):

### Good job

And there is already a good answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/243846/190910)!

I'm only commenting on your regular expression, even though I'm not so sure how your input ranges may look like. But, it would probably miss some edge cases. I'm assuming that these are all acceptable:

```
$80,000,000,000.00 - $90,000,000,000.00 per annum
$80,000,000 - $90,000,000 per annum
$80,000 - $90,000 per annum
$20 - $24.99 per hour
 $20 - $24.99 per hour
$20 - $24.99 per hour
 $20.00 - $24.99 per hour
```

and these are unacceptable:

```
 $20.00 - $24.99 per day
 $111,120.00 - $11,124.99 per week
 $111,222,120.00 - $111,111,124.99 per month
```

You can see your own expression in this link:

### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uDc4dd/1/)

- It would pass some cases that may not be desired, I guess.
- You also do not need to escape `.` and `$` inside a character class:

### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fYQ3Bz/1/)

#### Code

```
import re

def find_range(text: str) -> dict:
    expression = r'^\s*\$([0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{1,3})*(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?)\s*-\s*\$([0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{1,3})*(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?)\s*per\s+(?:annum|hour)\s*$'
    return re.findall(expression, text)


input_a = '$80,000 - $90,000 per annum'
input_b = '$20 - $24.99 per hour'
print(find_range(input_a))
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/n2UdOg/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/n2UdOg/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UREOgi/1/)

Comment: Thanks for this, especially those corner cases are very good points.